# Kubernetes node affinity - Assigning a pod to a specific node?

Tags: kubernetes, nodeselector

The k8s [node affinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/) documentation explains how to deploy a pod to a specific node by first tagging the node with a label and using nodeSelector to pick the node.

However, I have a use case where I have 40-50  deployments in a cluster and I want to add a new node to the cluster and set that node dedicated to one of those deployments/pods without altering all those deployments which don't have any nodeSelector specified

For example, lets say I have 3 deployments, with no nodeSelector defined and 3 worker nodes. This means k8s decides where the pods will be deployed and it could be deployed in one of those 3 nodes. Now I have to create a 4th deployment, and add 4th server and I want to dedicate the 4th deployment to the 4th server and also want to make sure that k8s won't schedule the first 3 deployments to this 4th node. How can I do this without going through all those 3 deployment scheme and apply a nodeSelector filter to not deploy on 4th node?  (It would be ok to perform this change on 3 deployments, but I am talking about 50s of deployments in real life scenario)

The only thing that I can think of is to [taint](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/taint-and-toleration/) the node but if I do it, none of the pods will be scheduled there.

Is there a better approach here to achieve this goal that I am not aware of?

Comment: This seems like an awfully specific constraint; why not let any pod run on any node?

Comment: For higher resource intensive workloads (nodegroup), node in different region where pod must run from that region etc. There are many

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you taint the 4th node, the 4th deployment with the toleration will be deployed on that node, while the other three won't.

Comment: oh, I didn't know that, my understanding was that if I taint the node, none of the pods will be scheduled there even if there is a nodeSelector. Let me give it a try

Answer (score 0):

You could use an [admission controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/#podnodeselector) to dynamically add `NodeSelector` into a pod spec at runtime rather than modifying existing deployment yamls. You could write any custom logic in the [mutating web-hook](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/extensible-admission-controllers/#admission-webhooks) to cater to your use case. For example you could have a label/annotation in the new deployment spec and based on the existence of that label/annotation you could dynamically add a `NodeSelector`.

[PodNodeSelector](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/#podnodeselector) admission web-hook is a good example to refer to.